# Using python from Rust problem: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Py_IsInitialized

Tags: python, macos, rust, anaconda

I am trying to call python code from rust (in order to Unit test some rust code). So I found CPython library which allows that.

```
// src/main.rs
use cpython::{Python, PyDict, PyResult};

fn main() {
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
}
```

```
//Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "python-rust"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["bashir ABDEL WAHED <bashir.abdelwahed@biogen.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
cpython = { version = "0.5.2", features = ["extension-module"] }
```

```
//.cargo/config.toml
[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]
```

When I do `cargo run`, I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Py_IsInitialized
  Referenced from: /Users/babdelwa/tmp/programs_for_documentation/python-rust/target/debug/python-rust
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _Py_IsInitialized
  Referenced from: /Users/babdelwa/tmp/programs_for_documentation/python-rust/target/debug/python-rust
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

**Environment:**

- I am using MacOS Mojave.
- I am using anaconda's python 3.8.3
- for rust:
  i am on MacOS Mojave.
  I am using anaconda's python 3.8.3
  And for rust:

```
active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.50.0 (cb75ad5db 2021-02-10)
```

Can you please help me understand the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The `extension-module` feature is meant for building extension modules, where the `python` executable loads your `.so`. The feature avoids linking against libpython, instead just using the existing symbols from the Python interpreter already running in the current process when the Rust code gets loaded. This improves compatibility with various Python interpreters (especially important for statically-linked Pythons).

If it's the other way around (your executable loads the python interpreter), you **must not** activate the `extension-module` feature. Then the Rust code will link against libPython which provides the necessary symbols.

Comment: I removed ```extension-module``` from features and so I got this error:
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
= note: "cc" "-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" "-L" ...  

= note: ld: in /Users/babdelwa...deps/libpython3_sys-c8335776a557cab4.rlib(boolobject.o), could not parse object file /Users/babdelwa/.../deps/libpython3_sys-c8335776a557cab4.rlib(boolobject.o): 'Unknown attribute kind (62) (Producer: 'LLVM10.0.0' Reader: 'LLVM APPLE_1_1100.0.33.17_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 11.0.0, (clang-1100.0.33.17)' for architecture x86_64
          clang: error: linker command failed ...